# android - showing original call log activity

Tags: android-activity, calllog

I use this code to show for example "phone status" activity :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

now what address should I use to show call log activity ?

- I don't want to use cursor to go through call logs !
- I want to load the original "call log activity" not create a fake one.

thanks

Comment: Does anyone have any clue about this ? I really appreciate it !

Comment: Could at least someone tell me if it's possible or not ?

Comment: still interested in an answer if anyone knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, should've called this intent :
Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON